# How to improve the smoothness of ContourPlot3D at the boundary

Tags: plotting, visualization

I want to `ContourPlot3D[]` a iso-surface. $3$ independent variable are `α1, α2, Ψ`, respectively. The codes are as follows (the equation is relatively complicated).

```
ContourPlot3D[-((π Cos[
     1/2 5 (ArcCos[(-1 + 
          Sin[(π ψ)/360]^2 Tan[(π α1)/
            180]^2)/(
         1 + Sin[(π ψ)/360]^2 Tan[(π α1)/
            180]^2)] - 
        ArcCos[(-1 + 
          Sin[(π ψ)/360]^2 Tan[(π α2)/
            180]^2)/(
         1 + Sin[(π ψ)/360]^2 Tan[(π α2)/
            180]^2)])] Cot[(π ψ)/360] Csc[(π ψ)/
     360]^2)/(360 Sqrt[
    Csc[(π ψ)/360]^2 + 
     Tan[(π α1)/180]^2] (-Tan[(π α1)/180] + 
      Tan[(π α2)/180]))) + (π Cot[(π ψ)/
   360] Csc[(π ψ)/360]^2)/(
   360 (-Tan[(π α1)/180] + 
  Tan[(π α2)/180]) Sqrt[
Csc[(π ψ)/360]^2 + Tan[(π α2)/180]^2]) - 
1/(2 (-Tan[(π α1)/180] + Tan[(π α2)/180]))
 5 Sin[1/
  2 5 (ArcCos[(-1 + 
      Sin[(π ψ)/360]^2 Tan[(π α1)/180]^2)/(
     1 + Sin[(π ψ)/360]^2 Tan[(π α1)/
        180]^2)] - 
    ArcCos[(-1 + 
      Sin[(π ψ)/360]^2 Tan[(π α2)/180]^2)/(
     1 + 
      Sin[(π ψ)/360]^2 Tan[(π α2)/
        180]^2)])] Sqrt[
Csc[(π ψ)/360]^2 + 
 Tan[(π α1)/
  180]^2] (-((-((π Cos[(π ψ)/360] Sin[(π ψ)/
             360] Tan[(π α1)/
             180]^2 (-1 + 
              Sin[(π ψ)/360]^2 Tan[(π α1)/
                180]^2))/(180 (1 + 
              Sin[(π ψ)/360]^2 Tan[(π α1)/
                180]^2)^2)) + (π Cos[(π ψ)/
         360] Sin[(π ψ)/360] Tan[(π α1)/
         180]^2)/(
       180 (1 + 
          Sin[(π ψ)/360]^2 Tan[(π α1)/
            180]^2)))/(Sqrt[
      1 - (-1 + 
         Sin[(π ψ)/360]^2 Tan[(π α1)/
           180]^2)^2/(1 + 
         Sin[(π ψ)/360]^2 Tan[(π α1)/
           180]^2)^2])) + (-((π Cos[(π ψ)/
        360] Sin[(π ψ)/360] Tan[(π α2)/
        180]^2 (-1 + 
         Sin[(π ψ)/360]^2 Tan[(π α2)/
           180]^2))/(
      180 (1 + 
         Sin[(π ψ)/360]^2 Tan[(π α2)/
           180]^2)^2)) + (π Cos[(π ψ)/
       360] Sin[(π ψ)/360] Tan[(π α2)/180]^2)/
     (
     180 (1 + 
        Sin[(π ψ)/360]^2 Tan[(π α2)/
          180]^2)))/(Sqrt[
    1 - (-1 + 
       Sin[(π ψ)/360]^2 Tan[(π α2)/
         180]^2)^2/(1 + 
       Sin[(π ψ)/360]^2 Tan[(π α2)/
         180]^2)^2])) == 0, {α1, 0 + 0.1, 
90 - 0.1}, {α2, 0 + 0.1, 90 - 0.1}, {ψ, 0.2, 180 - 0.2},
RegionFunction -> 
Function[{α1, α2, ψ}, α1 < α2],
Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.8], Orange],
FaceGrids -> {{-1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}}, 
PlotTheme -> "Scientific", PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

As we can see from the following picture, at boundary `α1 = α2`, the surface is far from smooth, (maybe because of infinitesimal in the denominator), I tried to use options `MaxReursion` and `PlotPoints` in `ContourPlot3D[]`, but result didn't improves..., So how can I improve this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tweak the plot domain so that it's not symmetric:

```
ContourPlot3D[...,
  {α1, 0 + 0.1 + 0.0001, 90 - 0.1},  (* slight offset *)
  {α2, 0 + 0.1, 90 - 0.1},
  {ψ, 0.2, 180 - 0.2}, ...]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]